# Oil specs for the 2013 Totem RC2 DH DPA

Tags: maintenance, fork

Does anyone know the oil specs for the 2013 Totem RC2 DH DPA fork?

On http://www.sram.com/rockshox/products/totem-rc2-dh the "Technical Manual - RockShox Front Fork Oil Chart - 2011 (44.85 KB)" only mentions 2 step (their previous system and not dual position air) and the latest PDF "2014 RockShox Suspension Fork Oil, Air, and Coil Charts (2.3 MB)" has all the forks apart Totem. I think that's because they are discontinuing Totem this year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a link to the 2013 SRAM fork oil chart. It includes the Totem. It's a PDF of a fairly complicated chart, so I can't post the info directly. I'll try to summarize it later today.

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByDywRkKVjrPeHRNVWJXS3ZhRzA/edit?usp=sharing

This is the updated 2013 pdf which includes the TOTEM RC2 DH DPA, listed as the 2-step.

It is confirmed by SRAM (owner of Rock Shox) that the 2-step and the dual position air use the same oil specs.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that in that PDF the Totem only shows specs for technologies: coil, solo air, 2-step. Mine is DPA (double position air) which is the replacement system for their old and problematic 2-step. RockShox is discontinuing Totem this year so the latest PDFs do not show Totem at all.

Comment: True. But they never published updated oil specs for the DPA, because its the same spec as the 2-step.  I'm pretty sure of that, but I'll check with my tech rep.

Comment: See updated link with 2013 PDF